# html и body не на всю высоту страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

На странице контента много которые все по высоте около 1500px.
Много гуглил, натыкался на такие же проблемы, где советывали html и body дать min-height: 100%; также min-height: 100vh; еще также с height, да даже position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; margin: 0. Но это также не помогает, вообще не понимаю в чем дело.
Я сам как-бы больше углубляюсь в бекэнд, так что в этом не так хорошо разбираюсь.

**Всем откликнувшимся заранее спасибо.**

Comment: `min-height: 100vh;` нормальное решение

Comment: не работает, пробовал

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` в шапке должно быь

Comment: он есть там, в самом начале проекта добавил

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что `html` и `body` не на всю высоту окна? Может подвал не прижимается к низу или фон у `body` не растягивается? Короче, нужны подробности и пример кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте дать цвет фону, думаю все у вас работает.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.full {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  www
</div>
```

Comment: Вот я сделал как вы сказали https://imgur.com/a/czrOeTz, вроде работает. Я просто подумал что не работает из-за того, что в инструментах разработчика браузера показывает очень маленькую высоту body https://imgur.com/a/AkGDlpb

Comment: да и еще только что заметил, что она не растягивается до конца страницы, а точнее до части соц. сетей https://imgur.com/a/b6vt0p2

Comment: Так у вас внизу контент

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за ответ